# Proper use of finished: in setAnimationDidStopSelector:?

Tags: ios, animation

I have some playing cards that flip over when you tap them. I want some stuff to happen after the flip animation is complete, so I have this in my `UIView` animation cycle:

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(flipAnimationDone:finished:context:)];
```

...which calls this:

```
-(void)flipAnimationDone:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void *)context {
    if (finished == YES) {
        // other stuff here
    }
}
```

Now, I need the `if (finished == YES)` bit in there, because otherwise the `other stuff` will fire *even if the user taps the card again mid-animation*, which is bad -- it needs to only happen if the flip animation completes completely :)

Problem is, this isn't working. If I have the `if` in there, the `other stuff` doesn't ever fire, no matter what. If I leave the `if` out, the other stuff fires, but possibly at the wrong time.

What am I doing wrong with the `finished` bit that is making it not work properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the documentation says the method signature is

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context;
```

Specifically,

> `finished`
>   An NSNumber object containing a Boolean value. The value is YES if the animation ran to completion before it stopped or NO if it did not.

So, you should make it `(NSNumber *)finished` and `if ([finished boolValue]) { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks! I had originally used `NSNumber` as per the docs, but it wasn't working (for what I see now was a completely different reason). When I checked around, there were a lot of sources saying that it was actually supposed to be a `BOOL` in there, so I changed it. Working perfectly now! :)